# Android BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME returning null?

Tags: android

I'd like to simply display my version name on my login screen, however, it's always returning null. I've defined my versionName in my app's gradle build as follows:

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.maplesyrupindustries.j.airportmeet"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.0.6"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And I am calling it in my login's onCreate:

```
    String build = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
    Log.e(TAG, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
    tvVersion.setText("Alpha " + build);
```

Yet, the build string is always empty. What gives?

Comment: What's the gradle version? >0.7 ?

Comment: the version is 2.10

Comment: Is the `defaultConfig` shown in your question from an app module, a library module, or something else? If you look at the code-generated `BuildConfig` class (in `build/generated/...` in your module), what does it look like? Are you importing the right `BuildConfig` and are not accidentally importing some other `BuildConfig`?

Comment: Please make sure when you clicking on the `VERSION_NAME` in `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` line it should point to `BuildConfig.class`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my issue. I was indeed pointing to the incorrect class..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please try this

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;//Version Name
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;//Version Code
```

Comment: I am aware this is another solution, but I'm curious as to why BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME is null?

Comment: If you use Gradle plugin/Android Studio, version code and version name are available statically in BuildConfig(like your code) otherwise you can use this way(like my code)

Answer (score 5):

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME is not working 
1). In Case when you import Wrong Package Please check your import Package 
2). Please import your application package & solve this issue permanently


  PackageInfo pInfo = null;
  try {
       pInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

 String versionName = pInfo.versionName;//Version Name
 int versionCode = pInfo.versionCode;//Version Code

 Log.e("keshav"," VERSION_NAME -->" + versionName +"versionCode -> "+versionCode);
```

**Output**

```
E/keshav:  VERSION_NAME -->2.0.4  versionCode -> 26
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` will return null like other values like:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.mypackage.myapp";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
}
```

The reason, because the file that contains this values `BuildConfig.java`, doesn´t exist until you compile the proyect, in fact the file `BuildConfig.java` is created inside folder `\build`, specifically `\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\....`

Like a better option to get `versionName` use this method:

```
public String getVersionName(Context ctx){
    try {
    return ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it so? And What can I do to build it back?